# Does a random string of infinite length contain all finite strings?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This may be a duplicate, but I have not found a yes/no answer.
So, does a random string of infinite length contain all finite strings?

Comment: When you introduce the notion of a "random string", you make it uncertain what the exact content of the string will be.  So one can say (once the notion of random string is more carefully defined) that any particular string of finite length will appear with probability one.   This is not the same as it being certain to appear, nor does it guarantee that all finite strings appear.

Comment: Random is such an ill defined word that the answer is not certain. You could randomly, uniformly pick from 0-8, then surely not all strings will appear as 9 does not appear.

Comment: If you found other times this question was asked without a yes/no answer, please link to those questions so we can mark them as duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - but only with probability $1$, under appropriate assumptions.

If you have an alphabet of $n$ characters and choose the $i$th entry in an infinite sequence independently with uniform probability $1/n$ then the chance that a particular character fails to appear in the first $N$ places is $ ((n-1)/n)^N$, which approaches $0$ as $N$ grows.

For finite substrings of length $k$ just think of your "alphabet" as all the words of length $k$, or modify the argument above.